# How do I know if I have the Lion recovery partition set up?

Tags: macos

I am looking to swap my HDD for SSD and OWC recommended methods 2 listed in [this link](http://eshop.macsales.com/tech_center/format2011/index.cfm)

1. Perform your drive upgrade.
2. Place your original drive in an external enclosure.
3. Boot to the recovery partition on your original drive by holding down Command-R and starting up.
4. Use Disk Utility to Restore to your new drive.
5. Restart or Boot your Mac to the new drive.

So I was wondering if my MacBook has Lion recovery partition set up properly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Terminal (located at `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`) type:

```
diskutil list
```

You know that you have a Recovery Partition installed if you see this entry:

```
Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB
```

Comment: For those who have a newer version of OSX I was able to check if the recovery partition exists with the same command in El Capitan 10.11.6 and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you have FileVault 2 whole disk encryption turned on, you can not see the Recovery Partition by holding down the Option key at boot, instead you must hold down Command-R to boot from the Recovery Partition.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can turn on the Debug menu on Disk Utility that will allow you to see and mount all hidden partitions.

See [View & Mount Hidden Partitions in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/23/view-mount-hidden-partitions-in-mac-os-x/)

> **Show & Mount Hidden Partitions with Disk Utility in OS X**
>
> First you need to turn on the debug menu:
>
> - Quit out of Disk Utility, and launch Terminal to type the following defaults write command:

```
defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1
```

> - Relaunch Disk Utility and look for “Debug” to appear alongside ‘Help’
>   Click on the new Debug menu and pull down and select “Show every partition” so that a checkmark appears next to it